# Trying to clear the fill of a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to clear the color pattern that I've put into a range of cells.  I ran record a macro to come up with the code.  However, now I keep getting an **error 1004, select method of range class failed**

Listed below is the code I'm using

```
Sheets("Outputs 2").Range("B19:M24").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.  This forum has helped me tremendously over the past couple of weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you renamed your worksheet since you recorded that macro?

Ensure that the name out the worksheet is exactly as it appears in your code.

Comment: Good point. I did not think about that, but I have seen it happen before just because Excel hiccuped.

Comment: If the sheet is renamed, one would get Subscript out Of range error ;)

Answer (score 1):

This happens sometimes and is nothing unusual. It just means that Excel was unable to set the selection. However, you can always use range references directly like so.

```
Sub ClearTintAndShade()
    On Error GoTo 1
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Outputs 2").Range("B19:M24").Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Exit Sub
1:
    MsgBox ("That sheet does not exist!")
End Sub
```

Comment: I just saw your answer. Had to delete mine :D

Comment: For OP: [Further Reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding to your answer.  I followed the code listed above and it worked.  Thank you for helping me out.